# Where does Woocommerce store the product information or how can I see what was last changed?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a site and the client ended up editing some of the products. Where can I see what they changed? My thought is to look at the database or files. I just don't know where the plugin stores the informaion for each product (I'm still don't completely know how wordpress works). I've tried looking at products page and sort by date, but my team has found some were changed but the date doesn't show the accurate date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most WP plugins, WooCommerce treats the products as a specific type of post, so you'll find them in the posts table as either `product` or `product_variation` types. WP also stores additional information regarding posts in the postmeta table.

However, without anything to compare it to, you will probably struggle to work out exactly *what* has changed; the posts have a timestamp that will tell you when it was last modified, but you don't really have much way of telling what the user changed. While WP does support [post revisions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions) they only apply to posts and pages by default.

Comment: The date last modified was very helpful, I know know what was changed and can just compare them with the new items. Much easier to do 13 items than 700+

Comment: Where would the prices and picture urls stored?

Comment: Prices would be in the post meta table; look for rows with the same post id number. Images in WordPress are actually treated as if they were posts; they have a post type of `attachment`. In the post meta field, look for the `thumbnail_id` number; that corresponds to the post id of the image itself, which you will find in the posts table. Don't be mislead by the name `thumbnail_id`; you can still get the full sized image from this ID.